# Sync playback and record with AudioKit 5

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, audiokit

I am trying to implement a simple recorder synced with a background track using AudioKit 5.
Unfortunately I faces latency issue when playing back the recorded file, along with the background track.

The latency values returned by the `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` are around 0,01 sec for input and output, when running on the simulator of my macbook pro.

However, the latency measured between the background track and the recorded one is around 1.4 sec.

Do you have any idea of what could cause this huge latency ?
And how to compute it with accuracy, so I can start the recorder late to compensate it ?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65600996/avaudioengine-reconcile-sync-input-output-timestamps-on-macos-ios

Comment: Thanks a lot @jnpdx ! I will have a look a the solution you suggested. It helps a lot.

Comment: How did you solve it in the end?